# GPIO in IO expansion board for Edison from DFROBOT

Tags: gpio, intel-edison

I have been using Intel Edison Module for my project along with this [IO expansion Board](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1244.html) from DFRobot.

But I came across a problem when dealing with the GPIOs: the output level seems to be quite unstable compared with the Arduino-Compatible Board.

Here is what I did to use DIO7 as output for both IO borads (called X-board and Arduino-board):

1. According to this [document](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/boards-and-kits/000005583.html), for the Arduino-borad, I first set an internal GPIO 255 to high so I can use GPIO48 (mapped to DIO7) as an output. Then I set GPIO 48 to high or low. Everything turns out OK.

   ```
   echo 255 > /sys/class/gpio/export
   echo 48> /sys/class/gpio/export
   echo high > /sys/class/gpio/gpio255/direction
   echo high or low > /sys/class/gpio/gpio48/direction
   ```
2. On the X-board, the procedure is quite straightforward. I set GPIO 48 to high or low directly.

   ```
   echo 48> /sys/class/gpio/export
   echo high or low > /sys/class/gpio/gpio48/direction
   ```
3. But when I monitor the voltage using an oscilloscope, the pin level on the Arduino-board is quite stable and fluctuates in a small range (10mV) while the one on X-board vibrates in 20MHz between 1-5V (sometimes 0-3V and sometimes stable), which is unacceptable.

I also try using mraa, but also no luck.

Does anybody know where is the problem or what have I missed? Any comment or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Here are the schemas of those two boards which may be useful:

1. [Arduino-board](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/edison/sb/edison_arduino_hvm_8_26.pdf)

2. [X-board](http://www.dfrobot.com.cn/images/upload/File/20150213181922jdvk59.pdf)

Comment: Looks like there is a problem with power rails. Did you use only USB to supply power? Have you tried external power supply with enough current?